# How to include the Title field of a content type inside of a Group?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

When creating a new content, is it possible to have the field *Title* inside a *Group* defined by me?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one way I'm aware of to do this. But since this solution is structural, it may not make sense to use it since the goal here is more for admin-usability.

You could use the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module ("ANT") create a new CCK field for the title, put it in the fieldgroup that you like, and configure ANT to populate the true title field from that new custom CCK field.

Comment: I thought about this too, but I was just thinking about a better way of doing this, without having that duplication... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Drupal 7 module [Title](http://drupal.org/project/title) which creates the title as a field that you can then move around in manage display.